# Firestore: Detach snapshots listeners in OnDestroyView, or in OnStop or OnPause?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

According to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm, three handlers could be used in order to detach my snapshots listeners from Firebase Cloud Firestore Database:

- OnDestroyView
- OnStop
- OnPause

I think the most convenient way'd be to detach it in `OnPause`, because this documentation states "The system calls this method as the first indication that the user is leaving the fragment.". Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which lifecycle you attached the listener. The following is the fragment lifecycle:

[image]

If the listener was attached in the method `onCreateView()`, then you need to detach the listener in the method `onDestroyView()`.

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onDestroyView()):

> `onDestroyView()`
>
> Called when the view previously created by `onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)` has been detached from the fragment.